# SQL Server Inner join exclude results not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables in my database t_recipe and t_recipe_ingredient having 1 to many relationship means one recipe can have multiple ingredients. I have to put a filter condition which should give me recipes which have ingredients included or excluded.

For included I have created below query and it works fine:

```
select * 
from t_recipe r 
join t_recipe_ingredient rexc  ON r.RecipeID = rexc.RecipeID 
where r.RecipeTypeID = 1 
  and rexc.IngrId in (110, 111)
```

But for excluded I am getting the recipes which have ingredients 110,111 however it should not return them, I think this is due to inner join which is including all other ingredients too and returning recipe:

```
select * 
from t_recipe r 
join t_recipe_ingredient rexc WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.RecipeID = rexc.RecipeID 
where r.RecipeTypeID = 1 
  and rexc.IngrId not in (110, 111)
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for formatting the query. I have removed the NoLock from my query. Now can you help me or suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want recipes without those ingredients, here is one method:

```
select r.*
from t_recipe r left join
     t_recipe_ingredient rexc 
     on r.RecipeID = rexc.RecipeID and rexc.IngrId in (110, 111)
where r.RecipeTypeID = 1  and rexc.RecipeID is null;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just produce the same result? Because you'd still get the Recipe IDs that have those ingredients unless those are the only ingredients in the recipe.

Comment: @zlk . . . No.  It is only looking for matches on those ingredients.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to exclude the recipe totaly by using not exists

```
select * from t_recipe r 
    where r.RecipeTypeID = 1
    and not exists(
     select null 
     from t_recipe_ingredient 
     where ingrid in(110, 111) and r.RecipeID = rexc.RecipeID 
   )
```

Comment: Your answer also works fine but query execution time of Gordon Linoff is better then yours. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select * 
from t_recipe r 
join t_recipe_ingredient rexc WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.RecipeID = rexc.RecipeID AND rexc.IngrId not in (110, 111)    
where r.RecipeTypeID = 1
```